# Initialize gem Artii on a File (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I know that I can initialize artii on the cmd with:

```
artii "word"
```

And WORD appears, but I cant find how to do this directly from a .rb file.

Comment: The documentation has a section [Examples](https://github.com/miketierney/artii#examples) (hint: "Integrated usage")

Comment: Yeah, I saw the documentation but in my case it´s not making the line break and it´s writting all in the same line.

Comment: You should edit your question to explain your specific problem, including what you have tried so far and how your expected output looks like.

Answer (score 0):

`Artii::Base#asciify` returns a formatted string:

```
require 'artii'

a = Artii::Base.new
a.asciify('word')
#=> "                        _ \n                       | |\n __      _____  _ __ __| |\n \\ \\ /\\ / / _ \\| '__/ _` |\n  \\ V  V / (_) | | | (_| |\n   \\_/\\_/ \\___/|_|  \\__,_|\n                          \n                          "
```

You have to print it in order to see the formatting:

```
puts a.asciify('word')
```

Output:

```
                        _
                       | |
 __      _____  _ __ __| |
 \ \ /\ / / _ \| '__/ _` |
  \ V  V / (_) | | | (_| |
   \_/\_/ \___/|_|  \__,_|
```